# Conditional Parsley JS validation on group

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js, parsley

We are using Parsley JS for client side validation and I have following scenario which I need to validate.

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<form id="demo-form">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    Do you want to enter values:
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no"> No
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select Year</td>
        <td>
          <select name="year" title="Select Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="year" title="Select Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="year" title="Select Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter Amount</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="amount" size="3"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="amount" size="3"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="amount" size="3"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

Validation requirements are:

1. User has to choose "Yes" or "No" (Choice filed is required).
2. If user chooses "Yes" then at least one drop down year need to be
   selected.
3. For any drop down whose year is selected needs to have some value.
   (Amoount filed not empty)
4. If user chooses "No" then Year fields can be kept on default value and amount can be left blank.

I would like to know if this type of validation can be achieved easily and efficiently in Parsley? I have created working copy for testing at the following  URL [Working example - CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKywWz)

I would really appreciate if somebody with better experience on Parsley JS, can comment on this.